# Covering a logo with your own and using the equipment in advertising

Tags: trademark, commerce, advertisements

Can I purchase a branded digital screen and cover the manufacturer's logo with my own; and then use the screen for the purposes of advertising my products, creating my own digital look?

The company I work for wants to buy 50 6' digital screens that have the logo toward the bottom border. They want to cover the logo with a Cruise line logo. Then we are creating the digital loop that will be shown on the screen, advertising products for sale. Is this ok?

Comment: Important question: are you planning on selling the modified TV screens?

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

You are not re-selling the screens, just using them in an advertising display.

Answer (score 0):

### No

Deceptive and misleading conduct in trade or commerce is pretty much illegal worldwide. What you are doing is a textbook definition of misleading and deceptive conduct.

Passing off someone else's products as yours gives them a right to sue you under the tort of passing off as well.

Comment: You do realise this is exactly what many screen manufacturers are doing anyway? A lot of branded screens use a Sony, Samsung or LG panels, especially if IPS or OLED, but don't have their logo on the outside... There's nothing wrong with what the OP wants to do - they aren't selling the screen.

Comment: @Moo but they do it under license

Comment: Not always, especially for manufacturers of things like video walls and the like - under concepts like the First Sale doctrine, it's perfectly fine to do stuff like this (if this applies in your jurisdiction).  The flip side isn't tho - badging rubbish as LG and attempting to sell it as an LG screen, for example.  But replacing the badging with your own is perfectly fine.